# Django Rest Framework Nested Serializers Create NOT NULL Constraints

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a new model entry with nested serializers, but I am getting a `NOT NULL constraint failed` error. I'm not sure why

`models.py`:

```
class Messages(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="reciever")
    message = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reciever.username
```

`Serializer`

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reciever = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Messages
        fields = '__all__'
        depth=1

    def create(self,validated_data):
        new_message = Messages.objects.create(
            sender = self.context['request'].user,
            # reciever = User.objects.filter(id=validated_data['reciever']),
            message = validated_data['message'],
            subject = validated_data['subject'],
            created_at = datetime.now(),
        )
        new_message.save()
        return new_message
```

POST request:

```
{
    "reciever":12,
    "message":"Hello World",
    "subject":"newtest"
}
```

Response:

```
IntegrityError at /api/messages/
NOT NULL constraint failed: index_messages.reciever_id
```

`views.py`:

```
class MessagesCreate(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
           mixins.ListModelMixin,
           generics.GenericAPIView):

 authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
 permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
 serializer_class = MessageSerializer
 queryset = Messages.objects.all()

def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
def post (self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.create(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is that `receiver` field cannot be `null`.

There are two ways of solving it.

First, you can make that field `nullable`:

```
reciever = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="reciever", blank=True, null=True)
```

Or, you should provide a value to this field when you are creating a message object in `create` method:

```
def create(self,validated_data):
    new_message = Messages.objects.create(
        sender = self.context['request'].user,
        receiver = User.objects.get(id=validated_data['reciever']),
        message = validated_data['message'],
        subject = validated_data['subject'],
        created_at = datetime.now(),
    )
    new_message.save()
    return new_message
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! the second option worked to solve my `NOT NULL` error, but now I'm getting, `TypeError at /api/messages/
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'User'` Which is strange because I thought that I would need to return a user object to save to my model as a the ForeignKey.

Comment: @tay_thomp you must be trying to call `int()` somewhere with user as a param. That's not correct.

Comment: The only thing I changed was using `.get()` instead of `.filter()` in the `create` method of the serializer... I'm not sure where `int()` would be getting called.

Comment: @tay_thomp if you closely look at the error, it should have a line and a file where it is called.

Comment: It's being called from `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 946, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)` So essentially when Django is trying to find it by primary key. It also seems that my `POST` request isn't sending back the integer to the Serializer. Instead, it's sending back a User object.

Comment: @tay_thomp can you post your view as well?

Answer (score 0):

you can try simple use fk_name`_id` for foreign key

```
reciever_id = validated_data['reciever'],
#       ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

S.O. to Jahongir Rahmonov!

Here is the answer:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
reciever = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
class Meta:
    model = Messages
    fields = '__all__'
```

Basically, I removed the custom create method and sent this as my `POST` request:

```
{
"reciever":
    12,
"sender":1,
"message":"Does this",
"subject":"Work"
}
```